# Obtaining a list of number from a list of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list or array of string, from which I have to retrieve a number from each string in list and store it in another list with these numbers only.

Here I want to obtain the number after "values=" and store in another array.

I am beginner and reviewed similar questions, but none of them worked.
I can provide the array if that helps you in any way.

```
[<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=56616>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=59501>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=109562>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=306290>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=11854>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3433>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=55551>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=40241>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=50313>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=20733>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=75596>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=19958>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=43132>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3558>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=36972>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=38991>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=12793>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=306360>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=8320>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=54925>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=7756>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=18249>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=6375>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=125554>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=30524>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=5077>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=24678>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3179>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=1714>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=7797>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=27459>]
```

Update 1.
this is what my array looks after using print command

Comment: `<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=56616>` is not valid Python. Did you mean for this to be a string such as `"<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=56616>"`?

Comment: @jarmod It can be valid python, if that is the _output_ from a class `__str__` method.  (I'm late to this party, and I see the question has been edited...)

Comment: Insufficient information. You should also show us the solution you wrote and explain what you expect it to do and what it actually does. Also, this looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is not a valid python. You need to add quotes.

```
lst = ["<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=56616>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=59501>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=109562>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=306290>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=11854>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3433>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=55551>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=40241>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=50313>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=20733>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=75596>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=19958>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=43132>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3558>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=36972>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=38991>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=12793>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=306360>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=8320>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=54925>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=7756>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=18249>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=6375>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=125554>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=30524>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=5077>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=24678>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3179>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=1714>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=7797>", "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=27459>"]
```

---

```
print(lst)
```

---

```
["<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=56616>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=59501>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=109562>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=306290>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=11854>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3433>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=55551>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=40241>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=50313>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=20733>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=75596>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=19958>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=43132>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3558>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=36972>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=38991>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=12793>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=306360>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=8320>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=54925>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=7756>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=18249>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=6375>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=125554>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=30524>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=5077>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=24678>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3179>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=1714>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=7797>",
 "<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=27459>"]
```

Split each item of your `lst` using `split()` in a list comprehension and convert to `int`

```
[int(x.split('value=')[-1][:-1]) for x in lst]
```

Output

```
[ 56616,  59501, 109562, 306290,  11854,
   3433,  55551,  40241,  50313,  20733,
  75596,  19958,  43132,   3558,  36972,
  38991,  12793, 306360,   8320,  54925,
   7756,  18249,   6375, 125554,  30524,
   5077,  24678,   3179,   1714,   7797,
  27459 ]
```

Comment: This would only work in the _exact_ format of the strings given. If you had, say, `"<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=56616 random=45''>"`, it would not work because there are characters after `value=56616`. So, this doesn't really selectively choose `value`, but rather everything from that cut at the start of `value`.

Comment: yes, you are right. I wrote this code according to OP's input. If they change the input, I will change my code:)

Comment: How does this handle a string which doesn't contain that `value=number` pattern?

Comment: Hey Chris, appreciate your comment. I did not use `regex` here in my code (it is there already in your code). I used a simple string method. As I stated earlier in comment. I wrote this code specifically for the pattern given by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your strings look like:

```
"<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=56616>"
```

You need only use a regular expression and a list comprehension to extract the desired value.

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r"(?<= \b value= ) \d+ \b", re.X)
>>> lst = ["<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=56616>"]
>>> [
...   m[0]
...   for x in lst
...   for m in (r.search(x),)
...   if m
... ]
['56616']
```

If you need these *as* ints, then the conversion can either happen in the list comprehension, or later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTMLParser and treat every item of the `list` like an html start tag. This would allow you to read any attribute.  Even if we do nothing but wrap your entire original printout in quotes, this way still works.

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser


L = "[<Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=56616>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=59501>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=109562>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=306290>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=11854>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3433>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=55551>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=40241>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=50313>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=20733>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=75596>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=19958>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=43132>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3558>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=36972>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=38991>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=12793>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=306360>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=8320>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=54925>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=7756>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=18249>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=6375>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=125554>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=30524>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=5077>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=24678>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=3179>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=1 value=1714>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=2 value=7797>, <Achievement name='Friend in Need' stars=3 value=27459>]"


class Achievements(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.__acv.append(dict(attrs))
            
    def feed(self, data):
        self.__acv = []
        super().feed(''.join(data))
        return self
        
    #find every instance of "key"
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        found = []
        for a in self.__acv:
            if (v := a.get(key, None)) is None:
                continue
                
            v = (str,int)[v.isdigit()](v)
            
            found.append(v)
            
        return found
        

a = Achievements().feed(L)
print(a.value)
```

output:

```py
[56616, 59501, 109562, 306290, 11854, 3433, 55551, 40241, 50313, 20733, 75596, 19958, 43132, 3558, 36972, 38991, 12793, 306360,
8320, 54925, 7756, 18249, 6375, 125554, 30524, 5077, 24678, 3179, 1714, 7797, 27459]
```

---

Due to your update, it looks more like you have a list full of classes that have a custom `__repr__`. If so, you could probably get your variables one of these ways:

```
values = [cls.value for cls in YourList]
values = [cls['value'] for cls in YourList]
```